# How do I diagnose the streaming operator problem: no match for 'operator<<'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I really didn't want to resort to this but I literally have no clue as to why my code isn't compiling (gcc).. ('template argument deduction/substitution failed' etc.)

Error message:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const EAN_code')
```

header file

```cpp
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class EAN_code {
  int ean_code;
  
};

class Order_item {
  EAN_code item_number;
  unsigned qty;
public:
  Order_item(const EAN_code&, unsigned);
  ostream& print(ostream&) const;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Order_item);

#endif
```

source file

```cpp
#include "header.h"


Order_item::Order_item (const EAN_code& code, unsigned qty) : item_number{code}, qty{qty} {}

ostream& Order_item::print(ostream& o) const {
  return o << qty << " x " << item_number;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const Order_item i) {
  return i.print(o);
}
```

Comment: @Biaaach put it in the question

Comment: How does the compiler know how to print a `EAN_code`?

Comment: @user4581301 oii that could be it, lemme just fix that

Comment: @user4581301 ya that's it thanks so much I'm gonna delete this post as it is a testament to my stupidity loooool

Comment: By the way, in the future, please add a more descriptive title. There are probably hundreds of thousands of questions which have compiler errors :)

Comment: Also don't use links to important stuff. Links rot. Definitely don't use links to file downloads sites. No way am I, or anyone halfway smart, going download an anonymous file from the Internet onto my PC. The Internet is littered with broken PCs because their users did that and got more than they expected

Comment: @cigien but how could I be more descriptive when I have no idea how to describe this to myself my hamster brain is being overloaded

Comment: @Biaaach I have suggested a title change.  streaming errors can be hard to spot for the faint hearted because you receive a wall of errors from the compiler.

Comment: @user4581301 @Den-Jason I'd love to upload it directly on stackoverflow but they provide no hosting service and adding the text into the post doesn't allow me to save the edit (too much text that isn't code but when I make it into code with ``` ``` it says too much code too little text lol) the error file is obv long

Comment: That is a problem. Template errors tend to sprawl, sometimes for pages. The trick is to pick out the error from the pages of suggestions and alternatives. Usually the first message is the most relevant, but picking out what you really need to show is  something that will come with practice. Mind you, once you know how to read the error messages well enough to pick out the relevant information, you probably won't need to ask the question. Practice doesn't make perfect, I'm living proof of that, but it does make the job easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
return o << qty << " x " << item_number;
```

specifically:

```
<< item_number
```

item_number is of type `EAN_code` and you have not provided an `operator<<` overload for it.  Use a similar pattern to what you've already done for `Order_item`

I suggest you change the question title to something like "how to find C++ streaming operator error".

Comment: I've done just that and it works thx is it possible to somehow call another method within the same line because the following is obviously a no-go
```return o << qty << " x " << item_number.print(o);```

Comment: Just implement a `print` method in `EAN_code` that returns a `std::string`

Comment: ok thanks, I thought I could overload the operator once more but it doesn't seem feasible

Comment: You can overload the operator as many times as you want - the signatures have to be different.  That's why you see a wall of errors when the compiler cannot find a matching signature; there are many already provided by the library.